# Android Studios does not autocomplete when add specific Android library to project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-preferences, android-library

I'm having an issue in Android Studio 2.2.3:

I have an empty preference file in `xml` directory:

xml/pref_popular_movies.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


</PreferenceScreen>
```

The problem is Android Studio doesn't suggest auto-completion to values from `string.xml` resource file.

And it happens only when I added this dependency to grade file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.1.0'
```

When I remove this dependency and sync the project again auto-completion back to work.

Here is my gradle files but I believe that the problem is not related to this because I tested in different projects (configurated by other developers) and the error still happen.

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.sunshine"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.1.0'



    // Instrumentation dependencies use androidTestCompile
    // (as opposed to testCompile for local unit tests run in the JVM)
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
}
```

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Cache and Restart of Android Studio after adding `preference` library to your project?

Comment: Yes, I did. It seams to be problem in the library.